# Schedule deploy rmarkdown in GitHub

Tags: github, r-markdown, rstudio

Is there any way to create a schedule to deploy a Rmarkdown in HTML format? I have a report that uses web scraping data, but the report in GitHub is in a fixed HTML, I want the report to update weekly in an automated way.
Any tips?
Note: I don't want to use shiny

Comment: Jenkins and cron are two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins or cron would require local setup/installation.

[GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) are executed on GitHub side, and [can be scheduled](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events).

For instance: "[Use GitHub actions with R Markdown and Distill](https://www.etiennebacher.com/posts/2021-03-19-use-github-actions-with-r-markdown-and-distill/)" from
[**Etienne Bacher**](https://github.com/etiennebacher): there are quite a few [GitHub Actions for the R language](https://github.com/r-lib/actions) to take inspiration from.